# How do I access my server with SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, apache-http-server

My computer runs `Windows 7` and my server runs `Linux CENTOS 5.5`.

What software do I need on my W7 machine to access my server with SSH?

Comment: Make sure to do further research on using SSH, as CLI access can be quite powerful and might cause you to accidentally kill something on your server (I'm making this assumption as you don't know about putty).

Answer (score 16):

[Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) SSH client.

Answer (score 6):

ALternatively if you prefer working in a UNIX like environment on your windows box you might install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) which also has the ssh, scp, ... commands, and of course all the other commands to make a Unix environment.

I always have a cygwin installed in a folder on every windows machine I regularly use.

Comment: +1 - It also comes with a X-Server so you don't have to run your linux apps in a console.

Comment: +1. Without Cygwin, a Windows box is crippled.

Answer (score 3):

putty + winscp works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use X11 forwarding over ssh using PuTTY and [XMing](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need

Just command prompt, putty is light and great.
for file transfers and light shell acess, winscp is good (filezilla works too for file transfer)
for shell access and remote windows viewing the one and only product is xming (which does not do the same thing as VNC, which is remote desktop. Xming just allows you to open single apps across a network using X on windows.)

Answer (score 0):

[Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) extended version with the possibility of obfuscated login it can get from here, with this name [( Potty )](http://www.mrhinkydink.com/potty.htm)
This version is recommended to use those (ISP) providers block port 22, they have
If you need more help, we're mostly here for the same :)

Good Luck

Comment: after running the potty, you can find it in the left side menu under-> ssh --> Kex -> Done! [Ahoora](http://www.ahooragroup.co.cc)